# Remove "Start back up" in File Explorer new Windows 11 update

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, onedrive

Since the new update that rolled out a few weeks ago, I have this "Start back up" message in my File Explorer:

[image]

It has been [suggested](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/remove-start-back-up-option-in-file-explorer/cb7af074-ce6a-4464-b7d0-058d47acfcae) to exit onedrive but I still want to use onedrive, I just don't want the "Start back up" message.

Comment: I really hope there will be some hack to remove this, because its very annoying button. Specially if you don't want to backup those Users folder - some apps put gigabytes of content in my Documents folder - thats not meant to be backed up! Also I use Desktop as a temp folder ... 
I am considering moving all my files to Google storage and uninstall Onedrive, its that annoying.

Comment: Try to use [ViVeTool](https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe) with the following command: `vivetool /disable /id:38664959,40729001,41076133`. Before doing that, query the current values using `vivetool /query` and create a System Restore save in order to be able to undo.

Comment: I also hope we can find out how to disable it from the RegEdit!

Comment: @harrymc Do they use the GitHub code to compile and exe from Visual Studio to run that, or is there an already compiled executable to download? Curious where you got the values you comma separated for trying too. Perhaps you have the exe compiled and the query gave you a list of ids that indicate those could be related. In domain environments, this does not appear to be an option I've seen with the latest Windows Updates.

Comment: A compiled `exe` is available on Github. The values I found from somewhere on the web (forgot where), therefore I advise some caution.

Comment: Were there any results from using vivetool ?

Comment: In Win10 the button appears only in the Documents and Desktop folders, so moving stuff out of those folders resolves the issue

Comment: @AJM: No, it wasn't this one.

Comment: Regarding the ViVeTool values - I found some information at [this link](https://old.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/16xxgqf/how_to_disable_the_new_file_explorer_for_the/), though they don't cite a source. Apparently the combination of 38664959 and 40729001 is *"New File Explorer home requirements"*, and 41076133 is *"New File Explorer home"*. On the other hand,  40729001 is *"WASDK File Explorer ... (Disabling it will entirely go back to the old one)"* - so surely there would be no need to pass in any other IDs when disabling it?

Comment: In [actual ViVe source](https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe/commit/97195a452776534c2c5973afd5b70e4ac9d3e3a9) we have: `XAMLFEHome,41076133`, `FERecommendations,38664959` and `WASDKInFileExplorer,40729001`.

Comment: Sadly, I don't know C# so can't really parse what it does with the values or names. Or whether Windows itself recognises them.

Comment: THIS WORKS!  Pay very special attention to this section:

"If for some reason you do not get the previous message, and it does not let you disable this message, what you have to do is, first, turn on sync for a folder. We will choose the folder that takes up the least space, and we activate it. Once done, just follow the previous steps, deactivate your synchronization and, in this case, you will receive the message to disable the function."

https://crast.net/493395/remove-annoying-onedrive-start-backup-message-in-windows-folders/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the button like this:

1. Open **RegEdit**
2. Go to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StorageProvider\OneDrive`
3. Remove or rename the key `StorageProviderKnownFolderSyncInfoSourceFactory`

**Edit:** This works instantly, but the key is recreated after reboot. You can prevent this by denying write permissions to the key:

4. In the left pane, right-click on the **OneDrive** key and then click **Permissions**. In the dialog click **Advanced**.
5. **Add** a new access entry for user **Everyone** of type **Deny**. Under **Advanced Permissions** just select **Set Value**.

Only other solution for me was uninstalling OneDrive. The option 1 by @cam-ashton doesn't seem to work with latest Windows 11 (23H2) anymore.

Comment: No negative impact found so far either

Comment: Thank you. To restart Windows Explorer, open Task Manager, and right click Windows Explorer select "Restart".

Comment: I renamed the value and it directly disappeared from the File Explorer, but after I rebooted, the value was automatically recreated and so the message comes back.

Comment: FYI, I have created a **scheduled task** which starts when I *open a session*, with *1mn delay*, to delete the recreated value: ```C:\Windows\System32\reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StorageProvider\OneDrive" /v StorageProviderKnownFolderSyncInfoSourceFactory /f``` --- I have restarted several times and for now it does the trick. Let's see if it will still work with the future updates...

Comment: I confirm that the value is automatically recreated ... I mainly put my computer to sleep so it's fine for me to delete it manually every time.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the instructions I've been giving to people to overcome this:

## How to remove “**Start back up**” in File Explorer on Windows 11

---

If you don’t want to use the backup feature of OneDrive, or you just want to get rid of the “**Start back up**” message that appears in File Explorer, you have two options:

- Disable the Backup Feature in OneDrive's Settings (**Preferred Method**).
- Uninstall or Disable OneDrive Completely.

### 1: Disable the Backup Feature in OneDrive's Settings

---

The easiest way to remove the “**Start back up**” message in File Explorer is to disable the backup feature in OneDrive settings.

Todo this complete the following instructions:

1. Right-click on the OneDrive icon in the taskbar and select **Settings**.
2. In the **Settings** window, click on the **Backup** tab.
3. Under **Back up your folders**, click on **Manage backup**.
4. Uncheck the checkboxes for **Desktop**, **Documents** and **Pictures**. Then click on **Stop backup**.
5. Click on **OK** to confirm.

You have successfully disabled the OneDrive backup and hopefully got rid of the “**Start back up**” message from File Explorer.

With this option you can still use OneDrive to sync and store your files online, but files from your local folders won’t be automatically backed up from your PC.

### 2: Uninstall or Disable OneDrive Completely

---

Another way to remove the “Start back up” message in File Explorer is to uninstall or disable OneDrive completely.

⚠️**WARNING: This will also stop syncing and storing your files online with OneDrive. This isn't recommended if you use other Microsoft services or apps that rely on OneDrive, such as Microsoft 365 or Windows Photos. Be sure you know what you are doing before following these instructions.**

If you still want to uninstall or disable OneDrive, here’s how:

#### Uninstall OneDrive

---

To uninstall OneDrive from your PC, follow these steps:

1. Press **Windows** + **R** to open the Run dialog box.
2. Type `appwiz.cpl` and press **Enter**.
3. In the **Programs and Features** window, find **Microsoft OneDrive** and click on **Uninstall**.
4. Follow the instructions on the screen to complete the uninstallation process.

#### Disable OneDrive

---

To disable OneDrive from running on your PC, follow these steps:

1. Press **Windows** + **R** to open the Run dialog box.
2. Type `gpedit.msc` and press **Enter**.
3. In the Local Group Policy Editor window, navigate to **Computer Configuration** > **Administrative Templates** > **Windows Components** > **OneDrive**.
   [01 - OneDrive - Prevent Usage of Onedrive - GPEdit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv9oo.jpg)
4. Double-click on **Prevent the usage of OneDrive for file storage**.
5. Select **Enabled** and click on **OK**.
   [02 - Enabled - Prevent Usage of Onedrive - GPEdit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmrwi.jpg)

That should be it. You have successfully uninstalled or disabled OneDrive from your PC and removed the “**Start back up**” message from File Explorer.

However, keep in mind that this might affect some of your other Microsoft services or apps that depend on OneDrive.

Comment: Unironically that was the answer and it was trivial. I just had to click on "Start back up",  select no folders to back up, and it'd work.

Comment: Glad it worked.

Comment: It actually only worked temporary. It's now back ...

Comment: Can you verify which option you followed?

Comment: I did "1: Disable the Backup Feature in OneDrive's Settings"

Comment: Can you confirm if you have just OneDrive Personal or both OneDrive Personal & Business?

Also is the account you login to the computer with Local Computer Account, Microsoft Personal Account, Domain Account and Computer Joined to a Domain?

Comment: I have two OneDrives running at the same time. One Personal and One Business. It is a Microsoft Personal Account.

Comment: Ok, could you try the following. Right click the One Drive BUSINESS Icon in the Taskbar  and run through the 1: Instructions. Then Right click the One Drive PERSONAL Icon and run through the 1: Instructions ensuring the toggles are disabled for "Documents", "Pictures", "Desktop", "Music" and "Videos". After doing this double check to see if the "Start back up" in File Explorer has gone?  Reboot the computer and see if it comes back? Or it comes back after a period of time? If it does it could be InTune or a M2M pushing a policy forcing the folders be moved. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: I already did untoggle all of it but the "Start back up" doesn't go away :/

Comment: In the latest Windows 11 (23H2), there is no Backup tab in Onedrive settings, and "Sync and backup" exists as a greyed-out option.

Comment: windows 11 pro 23H2: disabling it doesn't work. it actually made "start backup" blink in explorer. uninstalling onedrive made it go away but i'm yet to know the price i'll pay for doing it.

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work (anymore). There is no "Stop Backup" and the message in Explorer appears even with all folders unchecked.

Comment: Despite havin no backups enabled and the icon was there. I enabled `Music` which was empty, saved, agreed to the popups, then disabled it again and now it's gone, hopefully it will stay that way.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Before I removed OneDrive on my newest Win 11 system I changed the default folder locations (Documents, Music, etc.) so none of them were located inside the users>username>OneDrive folder. I have never gotten the Start Backup on my File Explorer no matter what folder I am in.